# Xamarin Forms Add Custom Toolbar at bottom

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page created using Xamarin Forms. I want to add a toolbar at the bottom of the screen like an overlay but doesnt change the actual layout of the screen. It should just overlay above everything and always be at the bottom.

It should showup only when there is a particular event. SO it will be added dynamically.

Any ideas - or if you can send point me in the right direction. I do not want to use any nuget packages.

Comment: What controls do you want in your toolbar?

Comment: do mean something like tabbed page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use AbsoluteLayout/Grid?

```
<Grid>
    <StackLayout><Label Text="Your content"/></StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="toolbar" VerticalOptions="End" Text="Your toolbar" />
</Grid>
```

Show/hide the control based on your event.

Comment: public void displayToolBar(ContentPage page)

This is the function I have - How do I add it to the page - Thats where I am stuck

Comment: If you want to do that way in every page, it's better to add a custom renderer for the ContentPage, so you could add/remove the desired toolbar.

If you haven't heard abt custom renderer, you could read it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

Comment: Thank you  - I think I will go with Custom Renderer - I guess no other option for now

Comment: You can use a ControlTemplate to easily add it to every page. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating/

Answer (score 0):

If you could show the code of `displayToolbar` it would be easier to write a code that suits your needs, but it should be pretty easy even without the code :)

You could do this with a RelativeLayout, AbsoluteLayout or a Grid but I recommend doing it with a Grid because is much lighter than RelativeLayout and has a lot more functions than AbsoluteLayout.

So, make the root of every page that you want to use `displayToolbar` a Grid with one row and one column. Add the actual content of the page to that Grid as a child view.

Now comes the part that would be easier with your code. When you want to display the toolbar, add the toolbar view as a child of the root Grid with VerticalOptions set to `LayoutOptions.End`.

That's it. The toolbar will be added in front of every view of the page and if you want to dynamically remove the toolbar, remove the root Grid's last child.

The layout would be something like this:

```
Grid root;

internal SomePageConstructor()
{
    root = new Grid
    {
        ColumnDefinitions =
        {
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }
        },
        RowDefinitions =
        {
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }
        }
    };
    root.Children.Add(actualPageContent, 0, 0);

    Content = root;
}

void DisplayToolbar()
{
    var toolbar = new StackLayout { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End };
    root.Children.Add(toolbar, 0, 0);
}

void RemoveToolbar()
{
    root.Children.Remove(root.Children[1]);
}
```

Note: I did this directly on StackOverflow, code could need some corrections.

From this sample, you could do an animation of the toolbar coming from below the page or something like it. Just change the `DisplayToolbar` and the `RemoveToolvar` methods.

Obs. Method names on C# are PascalCased (every word is capitalized) so your **d**isplayToolbar is **D**isplayToolbar.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. But this is restricted to Grid - The page can be of anytype and can have any layout. I want to make something very common - It can be passed by any page of any type or anylayout inside it - it should be able to show a toolbar at the bootm

Comment: You just have to add a grid as content and use the grid as the main layout... You can have any layout you want inside this grid. You can even create a new class like "ToolbarPage", inherit from ContentPage and add a new content property that automatically adds the content to the root grid. Really, it's either that or a custom renderer for each platform, and the custom renderer will need much more work

Comment: Update your question with the `displayToolbar` method that I will update my answer to have a custom class made for your toolbar